# Heroku nodejs application error can't find app/index.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I keep on getting the following error log

> Heroku Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'

Works fine on the local server?

```
State changed from starting to crashed
rwa@1.0.0 start /app
node index.js

module.js:538
throw err;

Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
```

I can't seem to get it to work on Heroku deploy, any ideas? I've added a correct Procfile (web: node index.js) and even added the `npm start` in `package.json` file correctly.

Comment: Have you added start script in package.json

Comment: @deepakthomas yes, well i added "start": "node index.js"

Comment: @deepakthomas oh wait, it somehow works now..

Comment: @deepakthomas What did you do?

Comment: Heroku looks start script in the package.json if it does not find it run its default start script which causes the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding start script in the package.json will fix your issues as Heroku looks start script in the package.json if it does not find it run its default start script which causes the error